# Mysql server uses 500% of cpu

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, crash, apache2, load

[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. As website goes down at every 300 concurrent users.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem unless you can supply code, and even then it could be a database tuning issue. Remember, the #1 cause of performance problems is failing to properly index your data.

Answer (score 0):

First step to consider is in your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # CAP suggested by V8.0 for avoid OOM.
```

This should be a Dynamic Global Variable that can be set with

```
SET GLOBAL thread_cache_size=100;
```

to avoid shutdown/restart.

top looks like ~2000 threads were trying to do something with ~50 running which may drive context switching through the roof.

Also please post your error log for any abnormal shutdown, there are likely clues of the leading cause.

Comment: @gurupal singh Have you made any progress?  Please let us know how you are doing with your use of MySQL.